# How to set up server side TLS in gRPC java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have gone through https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md, this PR https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/3992 and TlsTest in gRPC java. However, I am getting

```
Feb 13, 2018 8:44:53 AM io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
INFO: Transport failed
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 160301009401000090030334262ca5633e92e2f4d02af6ad
```

I am trying to do only server side TLS. 
Here's my code:

```
File serverCertFile = Utils.loadCert("server.crt");
File serverPrivateKeyFile = Utils.loadCert("server_pcks8.key");
server = Utils.serverBuilder(0, serverCertFile, serverPrivateKeyFile)
                    .addService(new HelloService())
                    .build();
```

Utils.serverBuilder code:

```
SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forServer(serverCertChainFile, serverPrivateKeyFile);
GrpcSslContexts.configure(sslContextBuilder, SslProvider.OPENSSL);
return NettyServerBuilder.forPort(port)
       .sslContext(sslContextBuilder.build());
```

The server starts up fine at 8080.

Here's the client side code:

```
Greeter.GreeterRequest greeterRequest = Greeter.GreeterRequest.newBuilder().build();

SslContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = GrpcSslContexts.forClient();
X509Certificate[] serverTrustedCaCerts = {
        Utils.loadX509Cert("ca.crt")
};
sslContextBuilder.trustManager(serverTrustedCaCerts).sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL);

ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8080)
        .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
        .sslContext(sslContextBuilder.build())
        .build();
GreeterServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = GreeterServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
GreeterServiceStub asyncStub = GreeterServiceGrpc.newStub(channel);

try {
    Greeter.GreeterReply greeterReply = blockingStub.greetWithHelloOrWorld(greeterRequest);
    logger.info("Response from HelloService  -- " + greeterReply.getMessage());
    assertEquals("Hello", greeterReply.getMessage());
} catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
    logger.warning("Exception when calling HelloService\n" +  e);
    fail();
}
```

What am I missing?

If I put a breakpoint in the exception log message, the exception thrown is

```
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 00001204000000000000037fffffff000400100000000600002000000004080000000000000f0001
```

On the server side logs, I see:

```
Feb 13, 2018 8:44:53 AM io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport notifyTerminated
    INFO: Transport failed
    io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: HTTP/2 client preface string missing or corrupt. Hex dump for received bytes: 160301009401000090030334262ca5633e92e2f4d02af6ad
```

Comment: Do the HelloWorldTls client and server pair added in https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/3992 work in your environment? If not, it could be an issue with the SSL implementation available to your client and/or server. Another thing to check is that the cert you're using is valid (you can confirm this by using it in the HelloWorldTls example setup)